# Escaping get_option( 'time_format' ) is nesserary?

Tags: escaping

I've submitted a plugin for review and it was not accepted as it needs some fixes with data sanitization and escaping.

One of the flagged examples was this line:

```
echo'<td>'.$date .' '.$time.'</td>';
```

last line of this code block

```
// date & time
$date_format = 'Y/m/d';
$time_format = get_option( 'time_format' );

$s = strtotime($row->created_at);

$date = date($date_format, $s);
$time = date($time_format, $s);

echo'<td>'.$date .' '.$time.'</td>';
```

I don't understand why $date or $time would need to be escaped since they are put through PHP functions strtotime() and date()

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should you escape these?

```php
$date_format = 'Y/m/d';
$time_format = get_option( 'time_format' );
```

**No.** That would be early escaping! Early escaping is very bad!

However, should you escape this?

```php
echo'<td>'.$date .' '.$time.'</td>';
```

**YES**.

Escaping is not about wether it's needed or not, if you ever find yourself saying *"It shouldn't be a problem because it's always a"* stop yourself and escape.

*Escaping is about enforcing assumptions and expectations. Why trust that it will be safe when you can escape and **guarantee** that it's safe?*

This protects you in multiple ways, e.g. if you use `esc_html` you've guaranteed the string will never contain HTML, even if you make changes in the future further up, filters get added, etc, **you always know that it's safe because you escaped at the moment of output.**